# How to reference other members in class from within an internal struct

Tags: c++, nested-class

I have a class that looks like this (details removed):

```
class MyClass{
        int seq[8];
        ...
    public:
        ...
        static struct{
            bool sorted();
            bool reverse_sorted();
            ...
        }test;
};
```

What I am trying to do is separate some of my `MyClass` member functions into nice little groups (structs).  The problem is that the functions in the "test" struct need access to the members of `MyClass`.

When I use the code above, I can define `bool sorted(){..}` but it doesn't make it part of the `MyClass` namespace like I was hoping it would.

My intention is to be able to write something like this:

```
MyClass M;

*do stuff with M*

if( M.test.sorted()){
    *do something*
}
else if( M.test.reverse_sorted()){
    *do something else*
}
```

Is there any way anything like this is possible? (How) could I allow the inner struct to have access to the class' data members? && Will I still be able to access the functions with the "`MyObject.test.function()`" syntax?

Comment: What about multiple inheritance?

Comment: When a function should use a certain object, you have to pass it to that function...

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your struct as `friend` of your class to achieve what you want, but you would have to provide a reference of your class. I would, to be honest, consider that bad style, but this works:

```
class M
{
    public:
        struct x
        { bool sorted(M & m) const { return m.sorted; } } test;

    private:
        bool sorted;
        friend class x;
};
```

Comment: The "static" may have just been a flaw in my logic. I was thinking a struct is an object, and I'd only need one copy to operate on the MyClass objects. I can see how I'm wrong there. I'm thinking it would just help sort my members functions out - I have about 40. I may have to resort to just prefixing them like Kirill suggested.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good - you would want to avoid `friend` declarations anyway, because what they do is to break proper encapsulation, and in this case it screams dirty workaround

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use simple thing:

```
class MyClass
{
        int seq[8];
        ...
    public:
        ...

        bool group1_sorted();
        bool group1_reverse_sorted();

        int  group2_something_else();
};
```

Prefixes will give you enough highlight while all problems will magically disappear... Why do you need these structs at all?

Comment: yeah i tried that at first... I think I may just have to resort back to that. Part of my problem is also that one of the groups has hash functions and an integer hash table, so I wanted to statically store one copy of the hash table & hash functions for MyClass to use.